# creating space between a link and a button

Tags: html, css

I have a button and a link beside each other, however, when I try to add padding between them the link goes onto the next line. I want to keep the button to sign in and a link to recover the user's password beside each other. But I would like a small gap between them.

I have created a fiddle which contains all of the code. https://jsfiddle.net/z6h1e3j4/

The below is my HTML for the simple login form. Thanks for any help given.

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST">
   <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
   <label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></label>
   <label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required></label>
   <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>
   <div class="link"> <a href="register4.php" id="underlining"> Forgot Password?
      </a>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: put an `&nbsp;` between them?

Comment: Also, I've been able to put a `20px` right margin on the button without the string going to a newline. Are 20 pixels non enough?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have never used that before, what is that?

Comment: It's a non-breaking space character, expressed as an html entity.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca would you be able to write out an answer with the margin-right:20px; because I can't seem to get it. Nothing is changing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with the mentioned `&nbsp;`
https://jsfiddle.net/gx5a2bqq/

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" 
   type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="link"> 
  <a href="register4.php" id="underlining"> Forgot Password?
</a>
```

an option with margin:
https://jsfiddle.net/ra7y2joh/

```
.link {
    margin-bottom: 50px;    
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please paste the fiddles as snippets on this site. Don’t post links like this. It reduces the usefulness of your answer.

Comment: I know, but it is two different answers using the code that the questioner passed, it would be an enormous answer, but I edited it to a better presentation :D

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried this about an hour ago, but only realising that my bootstrap container only allowed me to have a margin-left:3px; . But changed the width of the container, to allow for the margin to be bigger. (Incase anyone else has the same problem as me)

Comment: @cc111 - So you are fine with Link moving to new line, right?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh No i changed the width of the container, so I could make the margin bigger so both the button and link could fit on the same line

Comment: Yeah that's perfect. But take care with `px` while giving `margin`. There are possibilities, that at some point, it can break the constraint. And will push your link to next line.

Comment: that's right. but my answer is just a help, the values can be changed to %, to vw or to any other measure that helps better, I suggest % in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS margin property best addresses your question. The margin property is used to create space around elements, outside of any defined borders.

I added 10px of margin to the button.

`

```
        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
        <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
            <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
            <label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></label>
            <label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required></label>
            <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <button style="margin-right: 10px" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>
            <div class="link"> <a href="register4.php" id="underlining"> Forgot Password?
        </a></div> 
        </form><!-- /form -->

        <div class="forgot-password">
            Don't have an account? <a href="register4.php" id="underlining"> Create an account
        </a>
    </div><!-- /forgot-password -->

</div><!-- /card-container -->`
```

Answer (score -1):

`width:45%` to Button and Link
Which gives total width of 90%.

And `margin-left:10%` to link, which makes it 100%.

> Used `width` in percentage, to prevent the link from moving to next line.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body{
 height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(214, 229, 255), rgb(106, 144, 209));
 margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.card-container.card {
    max-width: 350px;
    height:400px;
    padding: 0;
}
 


label, input {
    display: block;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: inline;
}


/*
 * Card component
 */
.card {
    background-color: #a2b6de;
    /* just in case there no content*/
    padding: 20px 25px 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 25px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    /* shadows and rounded borders */
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


.btn-signin {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 36px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    -o-transition: all 0.218s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
    transition: all 0.218s;
    float:left;
    
}

.btn-signin-upload{
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 36px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: none;
    -o-transition: all 0.218s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.218s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.218s;
    transition: all 0.218s;
    float:left;
    
}

.form-signin #inputEmail,
.form-signin #inputPassword {
    direction: ltr;
    height: 44px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

  .form-signin input[type=email],
.form-signin input[type=password],
.form-signin input[type=text],
.form-signin button {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.form-signin .form-control:focus {
    border-color: rgb(104, 145, 162);
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgb(104, 145, 162);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgb(104, 145, 162);
}


.link, .btn-signin {
    display: inline-block;
    width:45%;
}

.link {
    margin-bottom: 50px;    
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-left:10%;
}

.form-signin {
    padding: 40px;
}

.forgot-password {
  padding: 25px 40px;
}

.forgot-password {
    color: #fff;
 font-size:16px;
    background-color: #5967b9;
    height: 130px;
}

.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:active,
.forgot-password:focus{
    color: #edf4fd;
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-container">
  <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
  <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">  <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
  
            <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
            <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
                <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
                <label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></label>
                <label><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required></label>
                <div id="remember" class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" name="submit">Sign in</button>        
                <div class="link"> <a href="register4.php" id="underlining"> Forgot Password?
            </a></div> 
            </form><!-- /form -->
          
            <div class="forgot-password">
                Don't have an account? <a href="register4.php" id="underlining"> Create an account
            </a>
        </div><!-- /forgot-password -->
                
    </div><!-- /card-container -->
```